# Is it possible to add external command line tools to Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible to use external command line  tools in Netbeans?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After searching and searching and searching, this feature is just missing in netbeans although it would absolutely straightforward to implement and has been ask by user for 2 more than years...

Regards,
Stéphane

Comment: Do you have a link to an feature request or something?

Comment: After one year and a half more, no, I could work back with eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Terminal window in NetBeans 7:
Open the menu, Window -> Output -> Terminal

Comment: it works for me (with a cygwin over windows), but that's quite a poor man's solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an Ant target? Ant files are quite comfortable to run from Netbeans.

```
<exec executable="${executable-full-path}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option I've found is to use jmarsault's plugin that he calls NetBeans Command Shortcuts.  This give you an icon in the command line where you can add command and terminal scripts to run.  The display shows in the output window.

[image]

Installation files are available here and he has kept it up to date with the newest versions of NetBeans.
[NetBeans Command Shortcut plugin](https://github.com/jmarsault/netbeans-command-shortcuts/releases)

Installation:

1. Download the .nbm file for your version of NetBeans
2. Open Tools / Plugins / Downloaded / Add Plugins...
3. Select the .nbm file and allow the installation of the plugin.

Comment: This cannot be installed anymore under version 9.0, even if adding 7.4 as a repository.

Answer (score 0):

In since at least version 9.0, there are two decent options:

1. Just create a script file. (I think you need the C++ plugin for this. Otherwise you have to create it outside NetBeans or as a text file.) In my case I created a JLinkGDBServer.sh that just executes JLinkGDBServer as a prerequisite to start an embedded debug session. This automatically sends the executable's output to a NetBeans terminal.
2. Add a tool to Tools/Options/Miscellaneous/SendTo. SendTo is a pop-up menu item for certain project entities, for example files but not the project. In my case, I could add a SendTo running the executable and use it by right-clicking on for example the .elf file (although for the GDB server I don't need any file name as an argument).

Comment: Where did you get that "SendTo" tool? There is no such tool in my netbeans 9.0 nor 11.0.